# responsiveness Issue - background Image is cutting off

Tags: css

I have a webpage on which I have one single image as the background image. I have three blocks of text on top of the background image.

When I render this page on a laptop it looks fine, but when I render this page on a TABLET, the TOP PORTION and the BOTTOM RIGHT PORTION of the image is cutting off. Perhaps the top portion is cutting off because of the MASTHEAD/Header. Im not sure though.

When I render this page on a CELL PHONE, the image is royally cut off from the top and bottom and right and left.

Basically, the responsiveness is not working when I run the page on a tablet or a cell phone.

Here is the CSS

```
body.test-page {
    background: url("images/testImg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center bottom / 100% auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 150%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
}
```

Can anyone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Samuel, could you include some HTML?

Comment: Hi Sam / Ronald, can you give some directions / code on how to fix this issue?